# How can I increment the variable more than one time when sensor event changed?

Tags: java, android

As you can see that I am trying to increment the variable 'c' when the accelerometer z-axis value greater than 12. But I can do it at one time, it will change the value 0 to 1 after executing the program. But I want to collect how many times the z-axis value becomes more than 12.

```
 @Override
        public void onSensorChanged (SensorEvent event) {
            textView.setText(event.values[0] + "");
            textView1.setText(event.values[1] + "");
            textView2.setText(event.values[2] + "");


            String s = new String();
            s = textView2.getText().toString().trim();
            Float t = Float.parseFloat(s);
            int c = 0;

            if (t > 11) {
                c++;
                txt.setText(Integer.toString(c));
            }
         }
```

Comment: don't initialise  c inside the onSensorChanged method. make c global variable

Comment: @a_local_nobody it's really worked. Thanks for your correction

Answer (score 1):

```
    int counter = 0;     

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged (SensorEvent event) {
        textView.setText(event.values[0] + "");
        textView1.setText(event.values[1] + "");
        textView2.setText(event.values[2] + "");


        String s = new String();
        s = textView2.getText().toString().trim();
        Float t = Float.parseFloat(s);
        int c = 0; // ???

        if (t > 11) {
            c++;
            counter++;
            txt.setText(Integer.toString(c));
            System.out.println("I need to learn how to use global 
                                variables.\n
                                also the thing has been greater than \"12\"
                                "+counter" times."
                              );
        }
     }
```

Also maybe using more meaningful variable names other than "textView#" would make it less of a pain for people to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Not global variables in general. But as correctly seen, the scope of c is wrong. It should be a member or class variable.

Comment: It's been decades since I checked, but I'm pretty sure any tutorial worth it's salt on global variable declaration contains information on variable scope.

Comment: If its really a worth tutorial it tells you to avoid globals (especially with that heavilly specific name "c") and teaches you encapsulation and object-orientation ;)

Comment: oh yea, and if it's really really worth it, it teaches you all about reflection and how to modify field mutators in order to get to some obscure field in some doubly-obscure instance of a far away class placed in the worst possible place, but hey, if your colleagues are doing it, might as well, am-i-rite? :))

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variable c as a field member like below:

```
public class MainActivity {
    private int c = 0;

    (...)

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged (SensorEvent event) {
        textView.setText(event.values[0] + "");
        textView1.setText(event.values[1] + "");
        textView2.setText(event.values[2] + "");


        String s = new String();
        s = textView2.getText().toString().trim();
        Float t = Float.parseFloat(s);

        if (t > 11) {
            c++;
            txt.setText(Integer.toString(c));
        }
    }
}
```